# reassigning variables with async/await?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await

I'm attempting to create a simple discord bot using discord.py for the fun of it.
I'm struggling to fully understand the way asyncio works and I'm having a problem overwriting/reassigning variables.

````
log_channel = "8765327525217520521501"

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!logchannel'):
        if message.content == "!logchannel":
            await client.send_message(message.channel, "```\n logchannel: 
            \r - Changes the channel this bot logs to. 
            \r - Takes the numerical channel ID as an argument 
            \r - E.g. !logchannel 123456789 ```")
        else:
            nc = message.content.split()[1]
            try:
                await client.send_message(client.get_channel(nc), "Testing new channel to be used for logs...")
            except discord.NotFound:
                await client.send_message(message.channel, "No channel was found with that ID.")
            except discord.Forbidden:
                await client.send_message(message.channel, "I Don't have permissions to use that channel!")
            except discord.HTTPException:
                await client.send_message(message.channel, "There was an error communciating with the server, please try again.")
            except InvalidArgument:
                await client.send_message(message.channel, "No channel was found with that ID.")
            else:
                await client.send_message(client.get_channel(log_channel), "Logging Channel Updated.")
                await client.send_message(message.channel, "Logging Channel Updated.")
                lmsg = 'Logging channel was updated to {} on {}'
                log.write(lmsg.format(message.channel,logtime))
                log_channel = nc
````

Trying to overwrite the log_channel variable causes a "referenced before assignment" exception. If I do not attempt to overwrite, then it can get the value of the variable fine.

I assume this is because of the way async works, however I do not fully understand this, I'm using examples as a guide.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with `async`/`await`. If you assign to a name anywhere in function scope, the name is local for the whole of the function (even before you actually assign to it). So you have two versions of `log_channel`: the local one, and the global one (that the local masks). The exception is caused because you try to read the local as the first line in the `else` case, when it's only assigned on the last line of the `else` case.

If you want to avoid creating a local override for that name, add:

```
global log_channel
```

as the first line inside your function, and all references (loads and stores) to `log_channel` will use the global version.